# Is this usage of Not correct?

Tags: python

Is this the usage of the `Not` operator correct?

for example of the code snippet:

```
if not A or B:
```

Does this translate to `if A is False or B is True`?

Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Why don't you try it out?

Comment: Please try it out, it should work

Answer (score 3):

you should look up to the [priority of operations](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~valerie/courses/fall10/155/resources/op_precedence.html). for this part:

`not x` > `and` > `or`

so it will be like `if (not A) or B:` here.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what is called the [`truth table`](https://plus.maths.org/content/maths-minute-truth-tables). Another one to understand is [precedence in python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). Now that you understand this try this out:

```
A = True
B = False

A or B  # Test 1: always evaluates to True if one of them is True
A and B # Test 2: always evaluates to False is one of them is False

not A or B # Test 3 Negates Test 1(A or B) cause or is evaluated first

if A or B ==True:
    print("One of the values in A or B is True")
else: print("Both are false")
```

I hope this helps. You will be fine, we all used to be there. Good luck.